# The verbs meaning "taking money out of your bank card/adding money to your bank card"

Tags: word-choice, technical

As far as I understand, the technically correct terms for adding money to your account and taking money out of it are "credit" and "debit", respectively. 
Yet, I am not sure how to correctly use these terms. 
For example, there's a warning in a software saying "Error due to exceeding bank card debiting limits".

Is there any better verb for saying this? I have sticked with crediting and debiting, but I'm not even sure that the people using this software will understand the terms.

Comment: You might get better answers on the Stack Exchange Personal Finance and Money site, for the right terminology for communicating with the users of your software.

Comment: You could use _deposit_ and _withdrawal_

Comment: But what's the problem with *Error due to exceeding bank card debiting limits*, please? That's hardly a model of literary brilliance, but what's unclear about it?

Comment: you are overdrawn!

Comment: A more general-purpose usage covering both debits *and* credits would be *Error due to exceeding bank card **transfer** limits*.

Answer (score 1):

To say *taking money out of your bank account*, we use the verb **to withdraw**

> [ELD:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/withdraw)  Take (money) out of an account.
>
> Example sentence: ‘normally you can withdraw up to £50 in cash’

To say, *adding money to your bank card*, we use the verb **to deposit**

> [ELD:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deposit)  Pay (a sum of money) into a bank or building society account.
>
> Example sentence: ‘the money had been deposited in a Swiss bank account’

Credit goes to @BoldBen who first posted this answer in [a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/417847/the-verbs-meaning-taking-money-out-of-your-bank-card-adding-money-to-your-bank/435907#comment998826_417847).

As for *to credit* and *to debit*

> [To credit in ELD:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/credit)  Add (an amount of money) to an account.
>
> [To debit in ELD:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/debit)  (of a bank or other financial organization) remove (an amount of money) from a customer's account. or Remove an amount of money from (a bank account)

Debit and credit seem to be used to used to describe transactions between two accounts (not necessarily from the same account holder), while withdraw and deposit are mostly used in relation to case, e.g. transactions in which cash money is taken out of or put into an account.

As they [put it here (quote from the article)](http://www.accounting-and-bookkeeping-tips.com/learning-accounting/accounting-basics-credit.htm), every credit action has a debit action of the same size associated with it:

> 'That's why they call it "double-entry accounting." When the cashier is telling you he or she will "credit your account", they are also entering a debit for the same amount that they are not telling you about. The same is true for the debits to your account - there is also a credit being made at the same time.'